# How to fade in text in a couple of seconds?

Tags: html, css, fade

i have a header text on my website. I like to fade it in in a couple of seconds (3 seconds for example)
 i can change for that section the html and the CSS. But what code do i need to place?

Thanks for help[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfmiJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XMdP.png)

Comment: What have you discovered and attempted?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please edit your question and use the snippet button to enter actual code and not pictures of code - see [mcve].  You may also want to take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site

Answer (score -1):

This is the easiest way I can come up with

```css
.paradise #anyone{
  animation: fadein 3s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to { opacity: 1; }
 }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<h2 class=“paradise” id=“anyone”>
Paradise anyone?
</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, this is wrong. don't use `-webkit-animation`. it does not work in all browsers. Just use `animation:`

Comment: You're right. I didn't think of that. I've changed it now :-)

Comment: So the first code i have to place in the CSS box and the second code i have to paste in the HTML box in the CMS?

Comment: If your header is h2 you should be fine with just copying the first thing in to your css

Comment: i have severall H2's on the website. So only this H2 should fade in. But i am gonna try to copy the css and place it

Comment: Then give the header an id or a class, and use `#{id}` or `.{class}` instead of h2 in the css

Comment: hmms, what is your mailadres? Then i can give you permission to login on a site where you can try it.